# How to redefine a standard function within a scope in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to redefine a standard Racket function, namely `display`, within a lexical scope, as in this example:

```
(with-custom-display (display "hello"))
```

This should work even when the code within the scope of `with-custom-display` is from a different library or even `racket/*` packages.

Is this possible? If so, how to do it?

EDIT:

If not possible in general, at least for the case of `display` and other write functions... could I somehow transform every output by parameterizing on `current-output-port` then redirecting the transformed output to the original port?

Comment: Do you want to replace uses in the syntactic scope or the dynamic extent? For example: If another file defines "display-all" that calls display on every element of a list, and you write `(with-custom-display (display-all (list "hello")))` do you want it to use Racket's original display (because the `display` does not appear within the syntactic scope of the body), or do you want it to use the overridden display (because a display happens while evaluating it)?

Comment: The latter. As with parameters.

Comment: Okay. If you care about dynamic extent then you can't override standard functions like `display`. If all of the display-calls you care about are to the `current-output-port` you can override that, however, you would have access to the characters that would be displayed, not original values display was called on. Can you clarify what you want more?

Comment: I am writing a lib to colorize terminal output. Would be nice to be able to colorize all output, not only that which uses my lib directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While its not possible<sup>1</sup> to globally replace arbitrary functions in Racket, you absolutely CAN change the standard out port that a Racket program uses (and by extension, functions like `display`). In fact, this is exactly what the [`readline`](https://github.com/racket/readline/tree/master/readline-lib/readline) collection in racket does, except for input ports rather than output ports.

Basically, all you need to do is parameterize `current-output-port` globally to be your special port. Since you want to ultimately write out to the original output port (but with colors), you can also grab the original output port before changing it to the new one. Your resulting code would look something like this:

```
#lang racket/base ;; init.rkt
(define orig-port (current-output-port))
(define new-output-port
   .... uses orig-port ....)
(current-output-port new-ouput-port)
```

(replacing `.... uses orig-port ....` with the implementation of your new colored output port)

And now, any file that requires `"init.rkt"` will get color in its default output port.

(Note though that if you have multiple files that do this same sort of thing, you have to be careful to make sure that they don't happen in an unsafe order.)

You can also make your `with-custom-display` form as a simple language extension by doing:

```
#lang racket ;; custom-disp.rkt
(provide with-custom-display)
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define orig-port (current-output-port))
(define new-output-port
   .... uses orig-port ....)
(define-simple-macro (with-custom-display body ...)
  (parameterize ([current-output-port new-output-port])
    body ...))
```

This is the general idea of how DrRacket is able to print output to a DrRacket specific repl, rather than your consoles stdout.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Normally anyway, there are usually ways to break things if you *really* want to. But that's almost always a bad idea. ;)</sub>